# How to fix "handleLoginFailure" on AEM Author in standby mode

Tags: aem, aem-6

We have two AEM Authors - Master and Standby. After tunneling to Standby and entering credentials we press anything or F5. After this we are redirected to login screen with error "Session timed out, please login again". In logs we have such error:

```
01.08.2019 12:09:29.977 *INFO* [qtp217415964-1719] org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator handleLoginFailure: Unable to authenticate null: Invalid token credentials.
```

On Master everything is Ok. The only thing which causes the problem is difference in runmode: primary or standby. When change config for standby (runmode: "standby"=>"primary") the problem disappears, but then we have two masters (which is not what we need).

We've read a lot of documentation, but all of them about how it works. But we can't understand root cause of the problem.
AEM v 6.4. Master and Standby are almost identical, but the described problem is reproduced only on Standby server.
I would be appreciate for any help.

Comment: When switching between author1 to author2, do you clear your cookies or use incognito browser?

Comment: The default authentication mechanism is token based, and that token is stored as a cookie. So if the cookie is maintained, but the backend server is changed, the token cookie does not work on the new server. Hope all of this makes sense.

Comment: Hi @AhmedMusallam,
we cleared cache in browser and the situation was the same.
Also, we used incognito tab-nothing has changed.
Also we cleared cache on standby instance-notching has changed.
The only what make difference-parameter runmode: primary/stadby in config file.